Ring of holes on the tube opposite the valve; what's the mechanism for puncture?
I just replaced a tube on my back wheel and it's got a slow leak. I can pump it up and ride for an hour or two, but when I come back the next day it's completely deflated. I did the "submerge under water" test, and found that the source was a hole on the tire side opposite the valve. Only one was an actual puncture, but there was a ring of marks on the tire side:

One of the rips at the bottom of the picture is the actual puncture, but the rest don't look too good to me either.
I inspected the tire at the location of the puncture, and didn't really find anything noteworthy (though it's possible I just don't know how to look).
Does anyone have an idea how this could've happened? My guess is some kind of rubbing on the tire, but other than that I'm stumped.

It kind of looks like there used to be a patch there that fell off. IIs there a small puncture in the middle of the ring that doesn't show up in the picture? Is there a patch stuck to the inside of the tire?

Good guess, but this was a brand new tire and tube.

I don't suppose you bought more than one identical tube, did you? I'm wondering if this  whole smoother region is from manufacturing

I'd go with manufacturing or storage related defect. Maybe the tube was folded at this spot, got warm and then was unfolded again? I am however confused by the clean looking seam in the center ...

@ChrisH I did indeed, and the smooth region is the default: the new tube was smooth everywhere with no difference between that region (opposite the valve) and the rest. I believe the lines are where it was pushed up against the inside of the tire.

Is it possible that the tube got caught on the tire at the edge of the ring so that the smooth region never contacted the tire? In that case it seems like the edge of the ring could've gotten stretched which might cause the punctures. If this is correct, what during the installation process could've caused that (or is it a manufacturing defect)?

That is a hot patch applied in the vulcanizing mold for that tube.
A factory patched error.
A defective tube that was repaired at the factory
Take it back to where you bought it and exchange it for a good tube.
Stem holes. I will guess that the operator of the machine that does that function got a little over zealous or they switched from a smaller tube and closer stem holes and punched two stem holes in that tube. They have a special patch as you can see.

If you inspect the boundary of the apparent patch and find that it is homogeneous, a more likely scenario is that you over-inflated the tube before installing it. The tube then folded over itself, which explains the stretching of the part of the tube surrounding the apparent patch. It also explains why the apparent patch still looks clean; that part has not rubbed against the tire.
The fold may last some time, but it's a weak spot that will, sooner or later, fail.
The solution is to inflate the inner tube just minimally. It still has to be limp when you position it. Doing so will give it a chance to distribute itself inside the tire when you pump it to its working pressure, and will reduce the chance it would fold over itself inside the tire.
Compare with the following image from this question.

Also see here. Had you inflated even more before the inner tire was constrained by the tire, a bulge could have appeared.
